Paypal v2 PHP curl Capture Order
My curl seems to be malformed or the header is missing some elements when I try to run it with PHP.
I have run this curl successfully in Postman:
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/MyOrderId/capture \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer MyToken" \
-H "PayPal-Request-Id: MyRequestId" \
-H "Prefer: return=representation" \
-H "PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id: MyMetaDataId"

But when I want to run it in PHP, it tells me the header is missing information.
Here is the PHP code:
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'generateAccessToken.php';

$orderID = $_GET['orderID'] ?? '';

if (empty($orderID)) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Missing order ID']);
    exit;
}

$accessToken = generateAccessToken();
if (empty($accessToken)) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Failed to obtain access token']);
    exit;
}

$url = "https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{$orderID}/capture";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken,
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "PayPal-Request-Id: " . uniqid(),
    "Prefer: return=representation",
    "PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id: " . time() . "-" . $orderID
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$httpStatusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$curlError = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($curlError) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'cURL Error: ' . $curlError]);
    exit;
}

if ($response === false) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Failed to capture order. No response data from PayPal.']);
    exit;
}

$responseData = json_decode($response, true);

if (!$responseData) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Failed to capture order. Invalid JSON response.']);
    exit;
}

if (isset($responseData['id']) && isset($responseData['status']) && $responseData['status'] == 'COMPLETED') {
    echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'id' => $responseData['id'], 'status' => $responseData['status']]);
} else {
    http_response_code($httpStatusCode);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Failed to capture order.', 'details' => $responseData]);
}
?>

Here is the error I'm getting:
HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request Connection: close Content-Length: 28 content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 x-served-by: cache-lon420138 broken content-length header


What is the exact error you're getting? In what way is your Postman request different from what you send via your PHP script?

Hi FiddlingAway, thank you for asking, the error I get is HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request Connection: close Content-Length: 28 content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 x-served-by: cache-lon420138 broken content-length header. So I am not sure what to make of this...

I actually fixed the problem lol.
I took the
    curl -v -X POST https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/MyOrderId/capture
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-H "Authorization: Bearer MyToken"
-H "PayPal-Request-Id: MyRequestId"
-H "Prefer: return=representation"
-H "PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id: MyMetaDataId"

command, I posted it in postman, and I converted it to  PHP -cURL, and I took that whole command, and I ran it, and I eventually got a success!!!
Here is how the source code looks:
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'generateAccessToken.php';

$orderID = $_GET['orderID'] ?? '';

if (empty($orderID)) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Missing order ID']);
    exit;
}

$accessToken = generateAccessToken();
if (empty($accessToken)) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Failed to obtain access token']);
    exit;
}

$url = "https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{$orderID}/capture";
$requestId = uniqid();
$uniqueOrderID = $orderID; // This should ideally come from your order system.
$paypalClientMetadataId = time() . "-" . $uniqueOrderID;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken,
    'PayPal-Request-Id: '.$requestId,
    'Prefer: return=representation',
    'PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id: '.$paypalClientMetadataId
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);


if ($response === false) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Failed to capture order. No response data from PayPal.']);
    exit;
}

$responseData = json_decode($response, true);

if (!$responseData) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Failed to capture order. Invalid JSON response.']);
    exit;
}

if (isset($responseData['id']) && isset($responseData['status']) && $responseData['status'] == 'COMPLETED') {
    echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'id' => $responseData['id'], 'status' => $responseData['status']]);
} else {
    http_response_code($httpStatusCode);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Failed to capture order.', 'details' => $responseData]);
}
?>

